# Force height of stacked tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two widgets (one above the other) that span the whole window in both directions. I would like for the one at the bottom to have a specific height, in particular to contain a single line of text without any unnecessary padding, while the widget at the top should span the rest of the height of the window.

I have tried fiddling with the padding and the options for `fill`, to no avail. How could I stack my widgets forcing the height of the one at the bottom?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x500')

f1 = Frame(root, bg='yellow')
f1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

prompt = Label(root, text='text here', background='red')
prompt.config(height=1, width=1)
prompt.pack(fill='both', expand=True, pady=0, ipady=0) # fill=X leaves gray padding above and below the label

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expand option tells the manager to assign additional space to the widget box. If the parent widget is made larger than necessary to hold all packed widgets, any exceeding space will be distributed among **all widgets that have the expand option set to a non-zero value**.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x500')

f1 = Frame(root, bg='yellow')
f1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

prompt = Label(root, text='text here', bg='red')
prompt.pack(fill='x')   # No expand!

root.mainloop()
```

Have a look at [Thinking in Tkinter](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net/) which I found very useful for learning `pack()`.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! And thanks for the link as well, it is very informative!